# How to autoclick my tab link with hash parameter

Tags: jquery

I have 4 tabs on my web page . But on page load always first tab is opened . I want to open other tabs on page load with some hash parameter in url 
Here is my code :

```
<ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"> tab1 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2"> tab2 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3"> tab2 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4"> tab2 </a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1"  class="tab active">

    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab">

    </div>

    <div id="tab3"  class="tab">

    </div>

    <div id="tab4"  class="tab">

    </div>
```

Comment: `window.location.hash = "tab1"`?

Comment: I think, you need to write some jQuery code for this, what checks, is there any hash in the url, and if yes, then trigger the click event.

Comment: Thanks !  It solved my problem , but now the problem is , my page is scrolling down when using hash url , how to prevent page from scrolling .

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it by php something like that.
pas an attribute on the click of a link eg mypage.php?tab=tab2
then get that on the page

```
 $tab = $_GET['tab'];
    <ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="tab <?php if($tab=='tab1')echo "active"; ?>"><a href="#tab1"> tab1 </a></li>
    <li class="tab <?php if($tab=='tab2')echo "active"; ?>"><a href="#tab2"> tab2 </a></li>
    <li class="tab <?php if($tab=='tab3')echo "active"; ?>"><a href="#tab3"> tab2 </a></li>
    <li class="tab <?php if($tab=='tab4')echo "active"; ?>"><a href="#tab4"> tab2 </a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1"  class="tab <?php if($tab=='tab1')echo "active"; ?>">

    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab <?php if($tab=='tab2')echo "active"; ?>">

    </div>

    <div id="tab3"  class="tab <?php if($tab=='tab2')echo "active"; ?>">

    </div>

    <div id="tab4"  class="tab <?php if($tab=='tab4')echo "active"; ?>">

    </div>
```